# How do I make a linux image which is of my current system?

Tags: linux

I want a really minimalistic version of linux to run on my raspberry pi. I need nothing on it apart form the tools to make it work. I can then install the things I need such as python, nano, ssh etc.

Is there a version of linux like that? I was thinking ubuntu snappy but wasn't too sure.

Secondly. If I got it configured exactly how I wanted on my system, is it possible to convert it make to a .img file so that I could flash it onto an SD card to use exactly the same settings on 3/4 of my raspberry Pi s?

Answer (score 2):

- Use [any os](http://elinux.org/RPi_Distributions#Comparison) (there are a few already trimmed down for you but I think [this one](https://github.com/debian-pi/raspbian-ua-netinst) is the smallest)
- uninstall what you don't want
- [make a backup](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/15763/how-to-do-a-minimal-size-backup-after-expand-rootfs-under-windows/31422#31422).
- optionally [shrink it](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/31805/truncating-sd-image/31813#31813)

Answer (score -1):

Gentoo linux is what you would want to "build" your OS from a minimal environment, but be warned: it will require quite a bit of time and effort to get from start to end-product. Arch linux is a minimalistic OS from the start, giving you only basic tools and programs. A search of the two will give you more details.

Copying a set up you like to another sd card shouldn't be hard. Just copy your current sd card to another using the `dd` command (`sudo dd if='/dev/sdb' of='/dev/sdf' bs=512k` for example), or a tool like `win32diskimager` Beware: `dd` has potential to over-write your hard drive! Double check your output path if you use this tool.

Comment: The distribution of Linux he starts with makes little difference if he is going to customize for minimalism anyway.

Comment: @user1133275 Not necessarily true, starting with a distro more fit to your liking means less work digging and removing. PiCore is tiny core's pi distribution, and it is quite different than raspbian.

Comment: Firstly its not likely he actually needs/wants minimalistic it makes no practical difference to a muti GB sdcard. There are multiple minimal versions for every distribution and if he really wants minimal custom/buildroot is the way to go. Any Linux branch will do, Like you say whatever "fit[s] to your liking".

Comment: Add a default install size to http://elinux.org/RPi_Distributions#Comparison if you want to see what's really small