# Truncating SD card image

Tags: raspbian, sd-card, backup

I backed up my Raspbian install with dd:

```
dd id=/dev/sdb of=/home/user/raspbian-backup.img
```

That gives me a `img` of the whole card (16GB). Then I followed a [tutorial](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/installation/installing-images/linux.md) to resize the image and used:

```
truncate --reference 2015-05-05-raspbian-wheezy.img raspbian-backup.img
```

Will this mess up my backup image? Is this the correct process or does the tutorial only work with "new" images? I don't have any SD card to dd in my new backup image and try it.

Comment: If you mean that the filesystem on the card was resized up at some point, yes, this will have wrecked the image, see http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/29947/5538  But if you have never changed the filesystem size, then it should be okay (presuming the size of the partitions in the 5-05-15 Raspbian image are the same as the one you used to install).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No that is the wrong way to do it; it makes the bad assumption that there are no files in the truncated part.

The correct way is to mount the img via loopback and resize the fs and partition before truncating:

```
IMG=2015-05-05-raspbian-wheezy.img
MDIR=/media/img_resize

#get partition offset
S=$(fdisk -l $IMG | grep Linux | perl -pe 's/ +/\t/g' | cut -f 2)
B=$(fdisk -l $IMG | grep Units | perl -pe 's/.*=//g;s/[^0-9]//g')
O=$(echo "$S*$B" | bc)

#shrink file system
L=$(losetup -f --show $IMG -o $O)
e2fsck -f $L
resize2fs -M $L
losetup -d $L

#get new file system size
mkdir $MDIR
mount -o loop,offset=$O $IMG $MDIR
U=$(df -B KB $MDIR | tail -n 1 | perl -pe 's/ +/\t/g' | cut -f 2)
umount $MDIR
rm -r $MDIR

#zerofree
L=$(losetup -f --show $IMG -o $O)
zerofree -v $L
losetup -d $L

#shrink the partition
L=$(losetup -f --show $IMG)
N=$(parted $L print | grep ext4 | perl -pe 's/ +/\t/g' | cut -f 2)
S=$(parted $L unit kB print | grep ext4 | perl -pe 's/ +/\t/g' | cut -f 3)
U=$(echo $U | perl -pe 's/[^0-9]//g' )
S=$(echo $S | perl -pe 's/[^0-9]//g' )
U=$(echo "$U+$S+1" | bc)
S=$(parted $L unit s print | grep ext4 | perl -pe 's/ +/\t/g' | cut -f 3)
parted $L rm $N
parted $L mkpart primary ext4 $S $U"kB"
losetup -d $L

#shrink the img file
E=$(fdisk -l $IMG | grep Linux | perl -pe 's/ +/\t/g' | cut -f 3)
NE=$(echo "($E+1)*$B" | bc)
truncate --size=$NE $IMG
```

This will shrink the official image by 37% from 3.1G to 2.3G (991M to 628M compressed)

Using [zerofree and 7z](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/15763/how-to-do-a-minimal-size-backup-after-expand-rootfs-under-windows/31422#31422) will make a small file for backup/storage/distribution if you don't want to resize the img file.

Comment: This is a bash script?

Comment: @AndiGiga yes; or likely any similar Unix like shell.

Answer (score 1):

As of today (1 Sep 2020), the `Image File Utilities` provide a set of tools to easily create and update fully *compressed* images of a Raspbian/RPiOS system while the system is running. I've used it on my RPis for almost a year now, and find it works very well.

If you elect to use `Image File Utilities` in an incremental or scheduled backup plan, know that the expected workflow is to use `image-backup` interactively (i.e. from the command line) to create an initial full backup; incremental backups may be automated (e.g. using `cron`). Restoration from a backup image to a µSD card is easily accomplished using [Etcher](https://www.balena.io/etcher/) or an equivalent.

`Image File Utilities` was "released" on Aug 1, 2019 in [this post to the Raspberry Pi organization's *Advanced Users forum*](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=247568#p1511694), where it is available for download. Support is provided by the author of `Image File Utilities` in this forum thread. If you prefer to use `git` to download and maintain `Image File Utilities`, you may use [this *unofficial* repo on GitHub](https://github.com/seamusdemora/RonR-RPi-image-utils).

Comment: I found this Image File Utilities very good, even DD newbies like me find it easy. ***Image File Utilities*** -  rpi.org.forums.advancedusers 2019aug01 
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=247568#p1511694. Many thanks for the new news.